# Example of compile-time substitutions worsening the program

Tags: compiler-optimization, lambda-calculus

Imagine a naive compiler of a typed lambda-calculus (to exclude a rather painful issue of nontermination and implicit recursion) that uses normalization (including substitutions under lambdas) as an "optimization".

For simple programs when most or all variables are used only once, the normalization leads to programs which are both shorter and faster.

To me it's "obvious" that in general it's not a good idea. That is, as normalization reduces sharing, there are terms that get worse because of the optimization. The term with 2 multiplications

```
\x -> let a = x * x in a * a
```

gets "optimized" into

```
\x -> (x * x) * (x * x)
```

with 3 of them.

How do I construct an example which gets arbitrarily worse? Is there a term that will likely overflow RAM when normalized?

We are working in a type system with strong normalization, so diverging is not possible, e.g. in a suitable subset of System F with constants and delta-rules.

Or with a "free" approach to adding constants like `mul`, e.g.

```
\mul x -> let a = mul x x in mul a a
```

So instead of adding constants they are just "extra parameters provided at runtime".

The question may seem to belong to SE Computer Science, but IMO it's really an entry level one so I think it's more appropriate here.

Comment: [cs.se] is a site for all kinds of cs-related questions, including the entry-level ones. [cstheory.se] is a place for research-level questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about stacking your slightly modified function on top of itself, like so:

let `p:nat->nat->nat` - opaque constant (or parameter).

```
q:(nat->nat->nat)->nat->nat->nat = \f:(nat->nat->nat).(\a b:nat.f (f a b) (f a b))

q p => \a b.p (p a b) (p a b)

q (q p) => \c d.q p (q p c d) (q p c d) 
  => \c d.q p (p (p c d) (p c d)) (p (p c d) (p c d))
  => \c d.p (p [p (p (p c d) (p c d))] [p (p (p c d) (p c d))]) (p [p (p (p c d) (p c d))] [p (p (p c d) (p c d))])
```

`q (q (q p))` expands to some enormous term

It grows exponentially. You can verify it in [Coq](https://coq.inria.fr/):

```
Section Expand.

Variable nat:Type.

Variable p:nat->nat->nat.

Definition q:(nat->nat->nat)->nat->nat->nat :=
  fun f:(nat->nat->nat) => fun a b:nat => f (f a b) (f a b).

Eval compute in (q p).
(*
  = fun a b : nat => p (p a b) (p a b)
     : nat -> nat -> nat
*)

Eval compute in (q (q p)).
(*
  = fun a b : nat =>
       p (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))
         (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))
     : nat -> nat -> nat
*)

Eval compute in (q (q (q p))).
(*
     = fun a b : nat =>
       p
         (p
            (p
               (p
                  (p (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))
                     (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b))))
                  (p (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))
                 =============SKIPPED LOTS OF LINES==========
                  (p (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))
                     (p (p (p a b) (p a b)) (p (p a b) (p a b)))))))
     : nat -> nat -> nat
*)
```

But Haskell, due to its laziness and sharing, able to calculate even large terms very quickly (in a fraction of a second):

```
Prelude> q f a b = f (f a b) (f a b)
Prelude> (q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
256
Prelude> (q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
65536
Prelude> (q $ q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
4294967296
Prelude> (q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
18446744073709551616
Prelude> (q $q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
340282366920938463463374607431768211456
Prelude> (q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
Prelude> (q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q $ q (+)) 1 1
13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084096
```